# DB optimization of trivial arithmetic calculation

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a calculation which I have to query the db. It's something like:

```
CM / 100  * CV / 100 * CL / 100
```

I was wondering if I will be better off query it like this:

```
CM * CV * CL / 1000000
```

Or will the DB do this optimization for me?

(I prefer doing it with the first one - because it is more clear for the reader - but I want to know if this will affect performence...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this kind of optimization is not done by MySQL (and I actually would be surprised if any other database would do this).

I also doubt, that you'll get a noticable performance improvement with this "optimization", therefore my advice is to optimize somewhere else. Write it whichever way you prefer.

You can check for yourself with

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
SELECT ...
```

The result will be a plan, how MySQL will execute the query (if it can and will be using indexes, and so on). After this you can do

```
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

In the result you will have the query, how the optimizer transformed it and how it will be used by MySQL.